# How can i add normalized records using sequalize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a method `User.createRider()` that adds normalized data to to the UserAttribute column.

```
var sequelize = require('../database.js').sequelize,
    Sequelize = require('../database.js').Sequelize,


    UserAttribute = sequelize.define('userAttributes', {
        key:        Sequelize.STRING,
        value:      Sequelize.STRING,
    }),
    User;

UserAttribute.belongsTo(User);


User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        createRider: function(params) {
            newUser = User.create();
            //this should be related to the user.
            UserAttribute.create({key: 'somekey', value: 'somevalue'});

            return newUser;
        }
    }
});



module.exports = User;
```

My problem is that I can't create the UserAttribute-model before the user is done, because I need the User-model to associate the userAttributes to and I can't create the usermodel first, because I can't create the class method before the userAttribute is defined. This seems like a common scenario. How can this be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you could create the user first and then add its id to the userAttribute when you create the latter. Like so:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {}, {
    classMethods: {
        // Returns a new user instance as a promise.
        createRider: function(params) {
            return User.create().then(function(user) {
                return UserAttribute.create({
                    key: 'somekey',
                    value: 'somevalue',
                    userId: user.id
                }).then(function() {
                    // Make sure this promise chain returns the user object, not the userAttribute object
                    return user;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```